# Bootstrap javascript not working in Django

Tags: javascript, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

I downloaded bootstrap and configured it in my Django application and everything was good after sometime the JavaScript stopped working but the CSS is working. I don't know what is wrong with it. The JavaScript stopped after sometime of development after first of all working well.

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width ,initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="author" content="Fon Desmond Ade">
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'tzuzz/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light  bg-secondary">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color: white">Tzuzz</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link nav-item" style="color: white" href="{% url 'tzuzz:login' %}">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" style="color: white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" style="color: white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" style="color: white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <br> {% block body %} {% endblock %}

</body>

<footer style="padding-top: 70px" class="fixed-bottom">
  <div class="card w-90">
    <div class="card-body">
      {% block footer %} {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'todo/js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
</footer>

</html>
```

Comment: You are going to have to be a bit more specific about *what* isn't working. Also note that Bootstrap 4 requires popper.js for a lot of its functionality, which you are missing in your template - but can't say if that is your problem without knowing what isn't working.

Comment: The problem is my drop-down menus do not work again and glyicons not also working.Thats it

Comment: Did you have it fixed? I am having same issue.